# The development server returned response error code:500 in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

[image]

I am on Windows 7 and tried to run react-native run-android. In my, emulator, it displays the error above. Can't seem to find the root cause of the error. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your React Native Packager is not started properly.
Try to do npm start again.
If you still face issue let me know in comment with description.

Comment: npm ERR! missing script: start

Answer (score 0):

It might happen if you have used `"scripts":` twice in the `package.json` file. If this is the case, try combining them. If there is no start script then add it as follows:

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    }
```